# Value object retrieved from a separate data source?

Tags: domain-driven-design, soa

I'm working on a system to model a Process.  One property of the Process is its rate.  I think the Rate is a value object since it has no specific identity.  This rate is retrieved from a service (think SOA, not DDD Service) I don't own.  The service can vary for each type of Process, since the Processes have teams and services built to support them that hold the data I want.  How do I organize that in DDD?

Here's some code to help explain:

```
class Process
{
    private final Rate rate;
    ...

    public Process( Rate rate )
    {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public Rate getRate()
    {
        return this.rate;
    }
    ...
}

class ProcessFactory
{
    public Process createProcess( ProcessSpecification spec );
}

class ProcessRepository
{
    public Process getProcessByName( String name );
}
```

If ProcessSpecification includes a RateSpecification that describes which service to call for rates, should the ProcessRepository be responsible for knowing how to load rates from the various other services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Process` is an aggregate, and aggregates are to serve as consistency boundaries, then it shouldn't reference data from other sources. Instead, you can retrieve the appropriate `Rate` value when a `Process` is being created and persist it together with the rest of the aggregate.

If the rate of a process changes outside of the scope of the Process aggregate, then you may need a synchronization mechanism which polls rate values from the service and updates the Process aggregates accordingly. In this case, the rate value is still stored with the rest of the aggregate.

Moreover, if the rate value is only used for display purposes, then it shouldn't be part of the `Process` aggregate even if it is conceptually part of it. In this case, just call the service whenever the rate needs to be displayed. Caching can be employed if performance is a concern.

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose Rate could be an aggregate as well, then.  My system will be tracking a mapping from my Process name to the appropriate parameters to provide to the other source.  That mapping is a value object because I persist it with my Process.  The Rate doesn't really have an identifier, but it is unique to the parameters and time range I provide in the request (almost factory-like, but the factory implementation is remote).  Ultimately, I'm building a model of the Processes, which have static relationships, and their Rates, which change constantly.

Comment: Further question regarding your last comment: if I'm calling a service like that, what roles would the service and the resulting Rate play as far as DDD terminology goes?  Is it a case where reality doesn't map well to the roles/concepts within DDD?  I don't think I'm asking for a Rate by identity, it's more a "give me the number of units processsed in this time span" question, so the Rate isn't even stored explicitly by the other system.

Comment: After some experimentation and discussion, accepting this one, since the idea of moving Rate out of the `Process` aggregate makes a lot of sense.  Rates are retrieved by a `RateService` when needed (creation and/or reconstitution).  In the system upstream from mine, Rate will appear as a value object, but in my system, I'm translating it from another bounded context into my own BC.